# Why is my ProxyTimeout setting not working in my Apache/AJP configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, jboss, ajp

I’m using Apache 2.2 and JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  I’m connected to JBoss from Apache via AJP.  Below is my configuration …

```
ProxyPass /cloudfront/ ajp://localhost:8009/cloudfront/

ProxyPass /app1/resources/ !  
ProxyPass /app1/ ajp://localhost:8009/app1/ connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300

ProxyPass /app2/ ajp://localhost:8009/app2/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/status.html https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
ReWriteRule ^(.*);jsessionid=.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R=301]

ProxyTimeout 600
```

When I try and connect to /app1 through a browser, I get a timeout (504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error) after about a minute.  I have confirmed I have extended teh client timeout on Firefox for instance, to 600 seconds.  Is there anything else wrong in the configuration above that is preventing extending the timeout period longer than a minute?

Comment: Well you are explicitly overriding the 600 seconds timeout on your `ProxyPass` line (reducing it to 300 seconds), Also the underlying service may implement its own timeout, so check that too.

Comment: Even if the override were working, the override is set to 5 minutes and I'm getting timeouts after 1 minute.  The underlying service is JBoss ... so by your reasoning, if I ran teh request against JBoss directly (bypassing Apache), then I should see the timeout, is that correct?

Comment: I agree the 60 second timeout doesn't make sense, I was just commenting about the 300/600 configuration. It maybe worth changing the log level to debug and then look if anything interesting appears in the error log. At the moment I can't see any reason for what you are describing. ALso maybe worth increasing the log level on the JBOSS side.

Comment: The JBoss log shows a "ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" after about a minute (I do not see this error when I run the request directly against JBoss).  Maybe there's some other Unix setting I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Well there certainly doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your Apache config. You only have 3 options, the `Timeout` directive which is overridden by the `ProxyTimeout` directive which is overridden by the `timeout` option on the ProxyPass line. 60 is the tomcat connection timeout, but that s the timeout between a connection being made and the request URI being sent, which is normally extremely quick.

Comment: The missing piece was there was an Amzon-hosted load balacner in front of all this.  We had to adjust the timeout there as well and then things started working.

Comment: Well you didn't mention that :-)